# required not working inside form in HTML when text box left empty

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="StudentID" placeholder="Ex: ZX12345"
        id="StudentID" pattern="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}" required><br> <br>
    <button name="submit" type="button" value="submit"
        onclick="studentId()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here even if i am not providing studentID then also its not showing any error even required is used and other problem i am facing is pattern not working here.

Comment: Its simple, The button type should be type="submit",So change that.

Comment: I am fetching json and if am using submit json is not fetched in javascript function onclick="studentId()"

Comment: You need to use AJAX for fetching JSON and for fetching you need to use method="get" instead of post

Comment: i am using ajax only and get method.

Comment: Can we see your full code?

Comment: actually even using submit in above code in place of button is not working. it is getting on same page, so no point of going further to other code.

Comment: That is because your form is missing an action attribute. If no action is given, default is current page. Can we see your studentId() method?

Comment: Yeah , Show the code in studenId()

Answer (score 1):

Use this code-

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="StudentID" placeholder="Ex: ZX12345"
        id="StudentID" pattern="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}" required="required"><br> <br>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"
        onclick="studentId()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The button type should be submit for checking the input fields.

Refer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/czmf7bk4/).

Comment: Please also use verb or verb phrase names like `saveStudent` instead of nouns.

Comment: The fiddle I linked is perfectly working. There might be some other error in your program. But for the question asked this is the right way to do. I can see everyone has answered the same, one person can be wrong not all. Try to debug your code

Comment: submit is working but with that i need to use event.preventDefault in js

Comment: Glad it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Update the type of button to submit.

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"
        onclick="studentId()">Submit</button>
```

Because form tag always checks the required field is empty or not on submit only.

Answer (score 1):

you should add ending slash in ur input
and remove type attribute from the button

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="StudentID" placeholder="Ex: ZX12345"
        id="StudentID" pattern="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}" required/>
    <button name="submit" onclick="studentId()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

here is a demo https://codepen.io/kjagannathreddy/pen/wRYpOm

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem is using in javascript method.

```
event.preventDefault();
```